# Issues with the task for the subsequent persons in Approval Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, approval, workflow-tasks-list

I have an issue with Approval Workflows that I can't wrap my head around.

**Background**

We are using the Generic Approval workflow for a document library, with multiple approvers and serial order.
We also have a web part summarizing a persons tasks, using a simple query: ContentTypeId:0x0108* AssignedTo:{User.Name} -Status:Completed

**Issue**

The first person on the Approvers lists, has the task showing up in his summary. However, when he finishes his task - the second person does not get the task in his summary. 
The task exists in the workflow task list, and the AssignedTo field is showing the correct user.

All other Workflow tasks are showing up just fine, it is only when the user is not the first person in a serial order workflow this issue occurs.

Edit: For the record - the content type for both the task that shows up and the task does not show up, is "Approval Workflow Task (en-US)" according to the list.

Any input is apprectiated!

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I can get the results even though the user name is the second person of approvers.

The difference is I use “path:"http://sp/Lists/Tasks"  AssignedTo=UserName  StatusOWSCHCS=Completed” as the Query text.

You can change the query text and check again.

Comment: I assume the path here is supposed to point to the SharePoint site's tasklist?
The issue with that is that this is a webpart that gathers all the users tasks from multiple sitecollections (both Workflow tasks and regular Tasks) into one webpart, which is why we run the query on the contentypes of the taskitem rather on a specific tasklist.